# BackdropScaffold containing a child AndroidView in the front layer

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose, interop

I am using a [`BackdropScaffold`](https://m2.material.io/components/backdrop) in compose where my front layer is an xml layout that I am integrating.

The main problem is that when the front layer is active and the back layer concealed, the scroll behaviour is not properly propagated to the front layer and because of that the front layer is not scrollable (Only few times is working)

I have tried to follow the following documentation, [a parent composable containing a child AndroidView](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/touch-input/pointer-input/scroll#nested-scrolling-interop), but still it is not working.

Here the code:

```
BackdropScaffold(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    appBar = { AnyAppBar() },
    scaffoldState = rememberBackdropScaffoldState(BackdropValue.Revealed),
    backLayerContent = {
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
        LazyRow(
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 16.dp),
        ) {
            items(cards) { card ->
                AnyCardItem(card = card)
            }
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(24.dp))
    },
    frontLayerContent = content,
)
```

The `content` is a `@Composable () -> Unit` as follow:

```
fun listComposable(): @Composable () -> Unit {
    return {
        val containerId by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(View.generateViewId()) }
        val container = remember { mutableStateOf<FragmentContainerView?>(null) }
        AndroidView(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            factory = { context ->
                FragmentContainerView(context)
                    .apply { id = containerId }
                    .also {
                        fragmentManager.commit { add(it.id, AnyFragment.newInstance()) }
                        container.value = it
                    }
            },
        )
    }
}
```

In the code above I am just converting the fragment that I need to integrate in the `BackdropScaffold` into a composable

And finally the fragment is created with the following layout:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:layout_behavior="es.lidlplus.common.FixedAppBarLayoutBehavior"
        >

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
            style="@style/AppBar.CollapsingLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="108dp"
            app:collapsedTitleGravity="start"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="14dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginTop="0dp"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar"
            >

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/white"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/activated_count_text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
                android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
                />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="75dp"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

It is a `CoordinatorLayout` that contains a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and a `RecyclerView`. Everything is displayed correctly but once the front layer is active the recycler view is not scrolling.

I tried to set `ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(view, true)` and the `BackdropScaffold` internally is using a `nestedScroll` state, but still the delta is not propagated to the fragment.

Any ideas?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The RecyclerView in your fragment is not set to be nested scrolling enabled. This means that the BackdropScaffold is not able to propagate the scroll events to the RecyclerView.

Comment: But I did it, with `ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(recyclerview, true)` as they describe in the documentation, and still the scroll is not propagated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe will be better to use another way to realized this issue.

It is CustomBackdropScaffold:

```
@Composable
fun CustomBackdropScaffold(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    appBar: @Composable () -> Unit,
    backLayerContent: @Composable () -> Unit,
    frontLayerContent: @Composable () -> Unit,
    isRevealed: Boolean,
) {
    Surface(modifier = modifier) {
        Column {
            appBar()

            AnimatedVisibility(
                visible = isRevealed,
                enter = expandVertically(
                    expandFrom = Alignment.Top,
                ),
                exit = shrinkVertically(
                    shrinkTowards = Alignment.Top,
                ),
            ) {
                backLayerContent()
            }

            frontLayerContent()
        }
    }
}
```

This implementation worked for me in trouble like in your question

Comment: It could be a solution, I used something similar but in that case how can you reveal the back layout scrolling? I can imagine that you are revealing and hiding the back layout just by clicking or something similar right?